# Regular expression for string that starts with 'http://'

Tags: php, javascript

I need a regular expression that will match anything that starts with 'http://'.

Comment: Up to where and what from? If this is to grab href attributes from markup, Regex are not the solution.

Comment: Try http://regexlib.com/

Comment: any why is this tagged javascript AND php?

Answer (score 2):

This will match everything up to the first whitespace: `^http://[^\s]*`

Comment: Strictly speaking, the OP doesn't explicitly mention that it's a URI - he just wants to match *anything* that starts with 'http://'

Answer (score 2):

Just look to see if the first 7 characters are "http://":

```
substr($url, 0, 7) == "http://"
```

There isn't any need for regular expressions here.

Comment: Agreed, but the OP asks for matches for anything that starts with 'http://', not for matches of http:// anywhere in the string.

Comment: Strpos will go off looking in the rest of the string too, so will be slower in non-matching cases :) We need the OP to tell us what's really needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: `^http://.*`

Comment: @Gordon, it will do what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

So basically, if you want to match a URL in a string, use:

```
http://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```